# How refresh ManagementObject result c#

Tags: c#, wmi, msmq, wmi-query

i need read some information about MS Queue by timeout (BytesinQueue, MessagesinQueue), but this data does not refresh.

```
var path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machine);
var scope = new ManagementScope(path);
scope.Connect();

string queryString = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue WHERE Name like '%{0}%'", queuePath.Remove(0, queuePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
var query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);

var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

var moItems = from ManagementObject x in searcher.Get() select x;
var moItem = moItems.FirstOrDefault();

if (moItem != null)
{
    BytesinQueue = (UInt64)moItem.GetPropertyValue("BytesinQueue");
    MessagesInQueue = (UInt64)moItem.GetPropertyValue("MessagesinQueue");
}
```

If i use Windows Management Instrumentation Tester, data does not refreshed, but there is a button "Refresh Object", which do what i need.

### How i can always get actual data, or refresh it?

[image: refresh object]

Comment: Did you write the WMI Tester program? I'm guessing when you click the **Refresh Object** button, the code you have displayed is called. When you step through that code, do you get all the way to the bottom? There may be an exception somewhere.

Comment: No, it built in windows. Start->Run->"wbemtest"

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get actual data, because you have to query it.

If you want to query the queue at set intervals, then you would need a timer.

Drop a Timer control onto your form.

Select the Timer Control and go to Properties.

Configure it to refresh every 5000 milliseconds (that's 5 seconds, or use whatever you want).

Double Click the Timer Tick event in the GUI. This should bring you to the code window.

Paste your code into this routine.